# Drop-down arrows in the select fields are not showing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am using a WordPress theme, and for some reason the HTML `select` elements look like plain `input` fields; although, when you click on them you can see the drop-down list.

I cannot find what code might be stripping away the drop-down arrows.

The following is what I can see in the CSS.

```css
input:focus {
outline: none;
}

select,
input,
textarea {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0; 
border-radius: 0; 
}
```

Comment: If you use an inspection tool, you can toggle the styles applied to the element on and off and figure out which one it is...  So, in chrome, right click the element and select "Inspect Element".

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything else related to it though. Is there an attribution for the select arrow? I'm wondering what code I should be looking for that controls the select arrow.

Comment: Get rid of the `webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: You only have four rules there. It doesn't take much effort to discover that `select { -webkit-appearance: none; }` is the cause of the problem. Change it to `select { -webkit-appearance: menu; }` instead.

Comment: Actually it was the border-radius I needed to get rid of, but that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 50):

The following is a basic select element with its options.

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Now let's see where your issue is:

```css
select {
  /*webkit browsers */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*Firefox */
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* modern browsers */
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;

}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

When you set `none` to `appearance` you are removing the arrow, and when you set `0` to `border-radius` you are removing the `border` of the `select` by default.

You can restore the arrow by setting the `appearance` to `menulist` (i.e., the default value) or `listbox` or `auto`.

**NB:** If you have hidden the arrow in IE with this rule `select::-ms-expand { display: none; }`, then you would need to set it to `display: block` to get the arrow back.

Comment: `menulist` ahh, thanks. I couldn't find how to add it back. once css style sheet out of my control set this property to none I needed a way to set it back.

Answer (score 19):

You have overridden the `-webkit-appearance` property for `select`, of which its default value is set as `-webkit-appearance: menulist;` by many browsers.

Answer (score 16):

I know I'm answering this question late, but my following CSS solution worked for me.

It may be helpful for someone else.

```
select {
-webkit-appearance: listbox !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer is correct for most, but it didn't work for me. However, the following line of code did the trick.

```
select::-ms-expand { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `select` in a `div` and on that `div` you can give `::after` element and style:

```
div:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #768093;
    font-family: #whichever font you wanna use# e.g Fontawesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    content: "\e842";
}

div:after{ 
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f096";
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above solutions but it was not working for UI, which was created using `jquery.min.css`. I have tried below css and it resolved my issue. Here I am targeting `.ui-icon-carat-d`, which shown dropdown arrow and setting dropdown icon there:

```
.ui-icon-carat-d:after{
    background: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pixel-perfect-at-16px-volume-2/16/5001-128.png") 95% 32% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was too getting the same issue, have got the drop down arrow after adding the below jquery file jquery-3.4.1.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js">
```

Answer (score -5):

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*webkit browsers */
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /*Firefox */
  appearance: none;
  /* modern browsers */
  border-radius: 0;

}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```